# How to serialize a java.security.Principal?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, serialization

I have written this code:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @RequestMapping(path = "/", produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Principal getUser(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        try {
            Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
            LOGGER.debug("User found" + principal.toString());
            return principal;
          } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.debug("User not found : " + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

But it throws:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been
>   called for this response

How do I serialize that object? What makes an object serializable for Spring Boot? During the execution, the actual object type is the `org.apache.catalina.realm.GenericPrincipal` implementation of `Principal`

As requested, here is the full stack trace:

> #ERROR#org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/loggedinusertest].[dispatcherServlet]##anonymous#https-jsse-nio-8041-exec-5#na#ab54cfe76#loggedinusertest#web#ab54cfe76#na#na#na#na#Servlet.service()
>   for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been
>   called for this response  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:211)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView.render(ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.java:218)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.handleErrorStatus(ErrorPageFilter.java:153)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:121)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:94)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   com.sap.core.connectivity.jco.session.ext.RequestTracker.invoke(RequestTracker.java:55)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
>     at
>   com.sap.cloud.runtime.impl.bridge.security.AbstractAuthenticator.invoke(AbstractAuthenticator.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>     at
>   com.sap.core.tenant.valve.TenantValidationValve.invokeNextValve(TenantValidationValve.java:182)
>     at
>   com.sap.core.tenant.valve.TenantValidationValve.invoke(TenantValidationValve.java:97)
>     at
>   com.sap.js.statistics.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.callNextValve(RequestTracingValve.java:113)
>     at
>   com.sap.js.statistics.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.invoke(RequestTracingValve.java:59)
>     at
>   com.sap.core.js.monitoring.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.invoke(RequestTracingValve.java:27)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836)

Comment: looks it is not a matter of serializable of `java.security.Principal`. Maybe some kind of a filter(or interceptor) which handle the request before this method already wrote `request.outputStream`. I recommand abjust logging level to trace and see what comes out.

Comment: when I return a `String` it works fine, that's why I think it's related to the serialization

Comment: @cassiomolin I mentioned it at the end of my question

Comment: I've seen that now :)

Comment: This code does not throw that exception, and the exception occurs prior to, and therefore has nothing to do with, serialization. Stack trace please.

Comment: @user207421 I provided it

Comment: There is no line of UserController code in stacktrace. Which means the actual cause of exception would be something else. Why don't you check the code of session injector?

Comment: could you try `public @ResponseBody String getUser(HttpServletRequest request, Principal principal)`? Still return plain string without any exception?

Comment: This exception has nothing to do with serialization, by inspection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By exposing a [`Principal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/security/Principal.html) instance (such as an instance of [`GenericPrincipal`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/realm/GenericPrincipal.html) from Apache Tomcat) in your web API, you may ended up leaking some sensitive details you don't intent to.

A better approach would be creating a DTO and then mapping only the principal details you want to expose to this DTO.

---

Despite the security breaches, let me just clarify what may be wrong with the serialization itself.

If you create an instance of [`GenericPrincipal`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/realm/GenericPrincipal.html) and then attempt to serialize it to JSON using `ObjectMapper` directly, you'll see it won't succeed:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Principal principal = new GenericPrincipal("john.doe", "secret", Arrays.asList("admin"));
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(principal);
```

The exception is:

```java
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: org.apache.catalina.realm.GenericPrincipal["userPrincipal"])
```

If you check the [`GenericPrincipal`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/realm/GenericPrincipal.html) source code, you'll see a `userPrincipal` field:

```java
protected final Principal userPrincipal;
```

Well, you could attempt to use [mix-in annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations), but it's probably not worth it. Just create a DTO and expose only what you need.

Comment: It's actually a stub, for tests purposes, so I don't mind exposing anything sensitive.

Comment: OK I see, it references itself, so it throws an Exception to prevent an infinite recursive serialization. Thanks for the insights!